# can i create java servlet as rest web service

Tags: web-services, rest, servlets, curl, httprequest

Can I use Java Servlet as a Rest web service?
And how to request using curl to servlet?

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use a (raw) servlet to create a REST service. But that is too much work knowing that there exists a standard API for this (JAX-RS JSR-311) and many frameworks implementing it :

http://www.jboss.org/resteasy
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html
http://jersey.java.net/